# Porting tables from an application written on top of MS Access Appliction to MySQL

Tags: mysql, ms-access, odbc

My brother uses an application called Kennel Connection - http://www.kennelconnection.com/screen.html that has a Microsoft Access backend.

He wants me to create come reports and display them on a webpage.  I know some PHP but freely(well maybe not freely) admit that I use dreamweaver as a crutch to speed along my php development.  Most of my experience in PHP is based on a mysql backend.

The database has about 20 tables though only about 5 are used on a regular basis.  Is there any reason I couldn't import those 5 tables in to mysql and create linked tables inside the application pointing to those mysql tables?  In the short term I would just port the key tables with the longer term goal of porting all the tables to mysql?

My biggest concern would be related not knowing if the application would have any hiccups writing to a linked mysql table rather then an internal access table.  Anyone have an experience with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would probably have to rewrite any queries at the very least. It does not seem likely that you need real-time data, and it is not difficult to write a query that updates a MYSQL table from MS Access. This could be run either through Task Scheduler, or manually.

Comment: You are correct in that read only would be good for now.  The first reports are lists of todays dogs and some monthly sales reports.  Your idea would certainly work in short term.  I am curious as to why you think i need to rewrite queries?  I bet you are correct but i couldnt think of a reason why this would be needed.  From what i can recall, if you query a mysql database via odbc from inside access you use access syntax.  Would love a little more info on in what cases you think a query rewite is needed as phase two i want to be able to update a few tables from a web page

Comment: For the most part that should be true, but there are some problems and you may find that you can get a better naming scheme and table design with new queries. Here is a bug example: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=7684

Comment: I like this answer.. As pointed out above there are possible bugs when moving certain type of access tables to mysql and hitting them by ODBC. that is an obscure bug but I dont think anyone can say for certain moving the tables to mysql linked tables or will or will not work without heavy testing. Remou's answer of setting up a task to copy the tables needed for reports is certainly the most safe solution for a production application.